# Exception: Flutter failed to run "/Users/minkhant/Documents/developement/mobile/android/gradlew

Tags: flutter, flutter-run

```
 Exception: Flutter failed to run "/Users/minkhant/Documents/developement/mobile/android/gradlew --full-stacktrace --info -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64
                    -Ptarget=/Users/minkhant/Documents/developement/mobile/lib/main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application
                    -Pdart-defines=RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ==,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQ0FOVkFTS0lUX1VSTD1odHRwczovL3d3dy5nc3RhdGljLmNvbS9mbHV0dGVyLWNhbnZhc2tpdC8xYWM2MTFjNjRlYWRiZDkzYzVmNWFiYTU0OTRiOGZjM2IzNWVlOTUyLw==
-Pdart-obfuscation=false
                    -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug".
                    Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
```

I have this error.i am search the how to solve this problem.Not answer what happen in flutter project.

I am trying the many process .don't work on it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.